# How can I connect my Android app to Amazon RDS MySQL Database using Php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Initially, I tried to put the php files in the S3 Bucket.  But, when I tried accessing the php files in the bucket using my mobile browser, it downloads the file instead of running the PHP code.

How can I connect to the RDS MySQL Database on AWS using PHP which would receive parameters and return JSON responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [s3 bucket](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) of aws is for storage. Here you can upload or download the file.

You need to host your api on the [ec2 instance](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) of aws. Once you do this you can make an api call from your android app